# Why does my homespun sizeof operator need a char* cast?

Tags: c

Below is the program to find the size of a structure without using sizeof operator:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int i;
  int j;
};

int main()
{
   struct MyStruct *p=0;
   int size = ((char*)(p+1))-((char*)p);
   printf("\nSIZE : [%d]\nSIZE : [%d]\n", size);
   return 0;
}
```

Why is typecasting to char * required?

If I don't use the char* pointer, the output is 1 - why?

Comment: Reminder:  Size of a structure may not equal the sum of the size of its members (fields).  Compilers are allowed to insert padding bytes between members in a structure.  One example is to align variables at address that are efficient for a processor to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

Because pointer arithmetic works in units of the type pointed to. For example:

```
int* p_num = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); 
int* p_num2 = p_num + 5;
```

Here, `p_num2` does not point five *bytes* beyond `p_num`, it points five *integers* beyond `p_num`. If on your machine an integer is four bytes wide, the address stored in `p_num2` will be twenty bytes beyond that stored in `p_num`. The reason for this is mainly so that pointers can be indexed like arrays. `p_num[5]` is exactly equivalent to `*(p_num + 5)`, so it wouldn't make sense for pointer arithmetic to always work in bytes, otherwise `p_num[5]` would give you some data that started in the middle of the second integer, rather than giving you the sixth integer as you would expect.

In order to move a specific number of *bytes* beyond a pointer, you need to cast the pointer to point to a type that is guaranteed to be exactly 1 byte wide (a `char`).

Also, you have an error here:

```
printf("\nSIZE : [%d]\nSIZE : [%d]\n", size);
```

You have two format specifiers but only one argument after the format string.

Answer (score 2):

**If I don't use the char* pointer, the output is 1 - WHY?**
Because `operator-` obeys the same pointer arithmetic rules that `operator+` does. You incremented the `sizeof(MyStruct)` when you added one to the pointer, but without the cast you are dividing the byte difference by `sizeof(MyStruct)` in the `operator-` for pointers.

Why not use the built in `sizeof()` operator?

Comment: And if you do use `sizeof` be sure to use it on the pointed-to object, not the pointer itself. `sizeof(p)` will give you the size of a pointer, where as `sizeof(*p)` will give you the size of a `MyStruct`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want the size of your struct in bytes. And pointer arithmetics implicitly uses type sizes.

```
int* p;
p + 5; // this is implicitly p + 5 * sizeof(int)
```

By casting to char* you circumvent this behavior.

Comment: Well, `sizeof` return the size in units of whatever a `char` is stored in (i.e. sizeof(char) is always 1). That's bytes in typical implementations, but is not required to be so...

Comment: That is true, but whenever you ask for a byte type you get the answer unsigned char :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the type of the pointer. This is what allows (for example) the equivalence between pointer arithmetic and array subscripting -- `*(ptr+n)` is equivalent to `ptr[n]`. When you subtract two pointers, you get the difference as the number of items they're pointing at. The cast to `pointer to char` means that it tells you the number of chars between those addresses. Since C makes `char` and `byte` essentially equivalent (i.e. a byte is the storage necessary for one char) that's also the number of bytes occupied by the first item.